# Inserting SQL data for one table into an html table using ASP.net or Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

For a bit of background info I'm a Network Admin/Systems Admin with very very minimal self-taught programming 'skills'. In the past I have just modified and tweaked existing code to get whatever I was looking for to work but I'm not having any luck with this current project. I am looking to add dynamic prices from a sql table into an existing html table for only a few of the records that are in the sql table.

I'm using a locally hosted server using IIS6 with a mix of ASP.net 2.0 and classic asp on the site with a 2008 MS SQL Server database.

I already have the connection to the db made in global.asa and am looking for how I can correspond each price to each html item number in the table.

(the sql code I copy/pasted from a different asp file with different intentions so if something looks completely off its probably because of that :[ )

Ex:

```
<html>
  <head>
<%
       sql = "SELECT * FROM tblProductCatalogue WHERE ( (tblProductCatalogue.CustomerID = 1 )  and (tblProductCatalogue.ItemNumber = ItemNumber)) " 
       Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
       rs.Open sql, conn, 3, 3

   if NOT rs.eof then
    rs.MoveFirst        

       DerivedPrice = rs("DerivedPrice")

    rs.close
    Set rs = Nothing

%>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Item Number</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>PartNumber1</td>
        <td>description1</td>
        <td><%DerivedPrice%></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>PartNumber2</td>
        <td>description2</td>
        <td><%DerivedPrice%></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>PartNumber3</td>
        <td>description3</td>
        <td><%DerivedPrice%></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Stan

Comment: How are the item numbers in the html table being populated? (hard coded in the html page or rendered dynamically off of a different select?)  If a different select you may be able to get price and item information at the same time which would be most efficient. Otherwise, you'll need to modify the select statement to pull back one or all of the items in the html table probably by item number if it's unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close!  You need a loop around your table rows.  Replace your table with this:

```
if NOT rs.eof then rs.MoveFirst

'...remove this code from your exampl (above), snip---'
   DerivedPrice = rs("DerivedPrice")

rs.close 'especially this code'
Set rs = Nothing  'and this code'
'---snip, end----'
%>
<%= rs.RecordCount %> Rows<br/> <!-- optional, for troubleshooting -->

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Item Number</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
<%
While NOT rs.eof  'loop through the dataset'
%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= rs("PartNumber") %></td>
    <td><%= rs("Description") %></td>
    <td><%= rs("DerivedPrice") %></td>
  </tr>
<%
   rs.MoveNext
Wend 'end while

rs.close
Set rs = Nothing
%> 
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like I messed up somewhere else as well, it's only grabbing the first record but the same sql statement used in a query on the server pulls 1428 rows, is it something with my cursortyp,locktyp values?
Thanks

Comment: Cursortyp, locktyp that you are using should give you a bi-directional read/write dataset.  There is nothing stronger.  I added a couple lines of code for troubleshooting.  It outputs the rowcount (should show 1428)

Comment: that gave me..Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'

Object doesn't support this property or method: 'RowCount'

Comment: Oh sorry.  Rowcount is SQL.  I meant RecordCount.

Comment: Sorry and thanks again for all the help, it was just a line in the table I was trying to comment out until I was ready for and messed up. Its working now. Thanks - Stan